# get dependent values on change of one select box in reactive form with add multiple rows

Tags: angular, typescript, dependencies, dropdown, angular-reactive-forms

I want to create dependent drop-down list with add more feature. I tried the below code:

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/add-more?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Basically this should be the flow:

1. on select of type, name values will be in second dropdown related to selected type
2. On select of name values, description values will be listed related to selected name

There are multiple row, all row will have own type, name and description values. the issue is when I complete first row selection with all values of 3 dropdowns and click on `add more` then in second row I select type to change the name values but it also changes the first row values. It should not change the value of first row.

I am not getting how to do this according to row added, also all values are populating from API so I can't call api in stackblits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must supose your nameList and descList are not an array of string else an array of object (*) So I imagine some like

```
this.nameList = [
 {id:1,typeId:1,name:"Name 1"}, 
 {id:2,typeId:1,name:"Name 2"},
 {id:3,typeId:2,name:"Name 1"}
];
this.descList = [
 {id:1,nameId:1,desc:"Description 1"}, 
 {id:2,nameId:1,desc:"Description 2"},
 {id:3,nameId:2,desc:"Description 3"}
];
```

So it's easy "filter" the options. But before declare a getter to acces the formArray

```
  get uomArray()
  {
    return this.productForm.get('uom') as FormArray
  }
```

And change the function to add a new FormGroup

```
  addmore() {
    this.uomArray.push(
      this.uom()
    );
  }
```

See how the .html becomes. the "formArrayName" is in a div alone, the [formGroupName]="i" is in the div you iterate nad you get the "value" of the array as `uomArray.value[i].type` I remove the classes to be more clear the code

```
<form name="productForm" autocomplete="off" [formGroup]="productForm">
  <div formArrayName="uom">
    <div *ngFor="let item of uomArray.controls; let i = index"
      [formGroupName]="i">
      {{i+1}}
      <select formControlName="type">
        <option *ngFor="let list of typeList" [value]="list.tyopeId">
             {{ list.typeName }}
         </option>
      </select>
      <select formControlName="name">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let list of nameList">
          <option *ngIf="list.typeId==uomArray.value[i].type" [value]="list.id">
            {{ list.name }}</option>
          </ng-container>
        </select>
        <select formControlName="desc">
          <ng-container *ngFor="let list of descList">
            <option *ngIf="list.nameId==uomArray.value[i].name" [value]="list.id">
              {{ list.desc }}
            </option>
          </ng-container>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

NOTE: **not** use the array "controls" of a form array or a formGroup, like your  `this.productForm.controls["uom"]["controls"] //<--WRONG` to get or iterate the array, the correct way is use `this.productForm.get('uom')`

**Update** from your comment, I need supoose you has a service that, according the value of "type" you has a list of nameList and according to the value of "name" you has a list of descList. But the only way is that you has an array of observables, really two (one for types and another one names), and subscribe to changes. The first is transform your function uom()

I supose then that you has a dataService that has two functions

```
getNames(res){...}
getDescriptions(res){...}

names$:Observables[]=[];
descriptions$:Observables[]=[];

uom() {
   const index=this.uomArray().controls?this.uomArray().controls.length:0
   const group=this.formBuilder.group({
      type: ["", [Validators.required]],
      name: ["", [Validators.required]],
      desc: ["", [Validators.required]]
    });
    names$[index]=group.get('type').valueChange.pipe(
      map(res=>this.dataService.getNames(res)
    )
    descriptions$[index]=group.get('name').valueChange.pipe(
      map(res=>this.dataService.getDescriptions(res)
    )
    return group;
  }
```

And you iterate over the observables using pie async

```
<select formControlName="name">
  <option *ngFor="let item of names$[i]|async">{{item}}</option>
</select>
<select formControlName="desc">
  <option *ngFor="let item of descriptions$[i]|async">{{item}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Actually, I am sure I am getting nameList and descList are as string array

Comment: but, then this values you received when change the value of type and name using a service, it is not like this?. I updated the answer adding this case

Comment: I'll try both and let you know the status. thanks for the help!!

Comment: hey, will your first answer can populate that on select of type? as I want name and description values dependent. e.g. first click on add more then typelist will be always there, now let say I select the type so according to selected type so namelist will be populated, now I am selecting name so according to name selected description will be populated. Hope, you understand this flow!! I can ask in backend to change the api response with your first answer.

Comment: I'll go with first option, will ask in back-end to change the response. Thanks for the help.

Comment: What if I want to append name list according to type when type is selected, the same for description, description should be appended when name is selected. Can you please help?